# How to convert column to row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need your help..
i have a dynamic query which returns data something in this format..

```
Item1  Item1Remarks  Item2  Item2Remarks  Item3  Item3Remarks  Item4  tem4Remarks
==
2      bla bla       5      bla bla       1      bla bla       4      bla bla
```

Item name can be vary (can be changed as data is dynamic). Item columns are containing Qty of Item.

Now i need data in this format.

```
Item    Qty Remarks
==
Item1   2   bla bla
Item2   5   bla bla
Item3   1   bla bla
Item4   4   bla bla
```

Comment: Post your query if you really want help.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341143/flattening-of-a-1-row-table-into-a-key-value-pair-table/7343619#7343619

Answer (score 5):

See [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

To specifically answer your question, you basically need a complex multi-column UNPIVOT query such as:

```
SELECT Item, Qty, Remarks
FROM ItemDetail
UNPIVOT -- This UNPIVOT gives us the Item column
(  
  Qty FOR Item IN (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4)  
) TheItem  
UNPIVOT -- This UNPIVOT gives us the corresponding Remarks column
(  
  Remarks FOR ItemRemarks IN (Item1Remarks, Item2Remarks, 
                              Item3Remarks, Item4Remarks)  
) Ct  
WHERE RIGHT(Item,1)=SUBSTRING(ItemRemarks,5,1) -- Match items with their remarks
```

You didn't specify the name of your table, so replace `ItemDetail` with its actual name.