# Flatten table with large number of columns

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, transpose, cross-apply

I have a transactional table with 100+ columns and each row is uniquely identified by an `id` column. For a data export requirement, we need to make export the table flat - aka, `id/column_name/column_value` format.

Using `PIVOT` will work here. However, the number of columns are very dynamic nature. By this, I mean : there could be 10 additional columns in near future. Some columns might get dropped. This is another reason for exporting as a name/value pair.

I checked the possiblity of using `XML PATH` as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343619/640070).

However, the issue is to associate the key/value pair to the id of the initial table. That is, the final table should look like this (the SQL Fiddle of an existing schema is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/609167/1/0)):

```
select * from finaltable;

idLoop|key|value

38215|DCC_Avg|29.29 

38215|DCC_StdDev|0.762

38215|DCC_Count|13.00 

..

..

38221|DCC_Avg|0

38221|DCC_StdDev|0

38221|DCC_Count|9.4
```

etc.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: There are many questions already about [dynamic pivots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+dynamic+pivot); you may get a better response if you show what you've tried so far.