# Unpivot SQL each row in SQL table to key-value pairs with group IDs

Tags: sql-server, key-value, unpivot

Running SQL Server 2012, I have a table in the following format:

```
ENC_ID    | Name     | ED_YN    | Seq
-------------------------------------
1234      | John     | Y        | 1
1234      | Sally    | N        | 2   
2345      | Chris    | N        | 1
2345      | Sally    | N        | 2
```

I would like to unpivot this into a entity-attribute-value list (if that's the right terminology - I am thinking of them as key-value pairs grouped by IDs), with the following format:

```
ENC_ID    | Seq      | Key     | Value
--------------------------------------
1234      | 1        | Name    | John
1234      | 1        | ED_YN   | Y
1234      | 2        | Name    | Sally
1234      | 2        | ED_YN   | N
2345      | 1        | Name    | Chris
2345      | 1        | ED_YN   | N
2345      | 2        | Name    | Sally
2345      | 2        | ED_YN   | N
```

I have seen various answers to this using UNION or UNPIVOT, but these solutions tend to be long and must be closely customized to the table. I'm looking for a solution that can be reused without a great deal of rewriting as this pattern solves a problem I expect to run into frequently (ingesting data from star-schema into Tableau via extracts, where I don't necessarily know the number of value columns).

The closest thing I've found to solve this is [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341143/flattening-of-a-1-row-table-into-a-key-value-pair-table) but I haven't had success altering the solution to add ENC_ID and Seq to each row in the result table.

Thanks.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, you're not trying to "unpivot" the table, you're trying to "denormalize" it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I will use `Cross Apply` with `table valued Constructor` to do this unpivoting

```
select ENC_ID, Seq, Key, Value 
from yourtable
cross apply
(values ('Name',Name),
        ('ED_YN',ED_YN)) CS (Key,Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query. This uses classic `UNPIVOT` syntax.
Since I am unsure about your column types I have casted both of them as `varchar(100)`. You can increase length from 100.

Working sql fiddle demo link :

```
select enc_id,seq, k [key],v [value] from
(select enc_id,seq,cast(name as varchar(100)) as name, cast(ed_yn as varchar(100)) as ed_yn  from r)s
UNPIVOT
( v for k in ([name],[ed_yn])
)up
```