# SQL Transpose Data with Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transpose, unpivot

I am trying to transpose data in a SQL Server table with one row of data but with several columns, all into one column along with their respective column headers.

Original Data Table:

```
**TABLE Column Names:**   Id, ColumnA , ColumnB , ColumnC , StartDate

**Data:**                 1, 'aa' , 'bb' , 'cc', 2016-10-10
```

Required Format of Data:

```
**ColumnName     Values**
Id               1
ColumnA         aa
ColumnB         bb
ColumnC         cc
StartDate     2016-10-10


CREATE DATABASE ToDelete
GO

USE [ToDelete]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sourceData](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [ColumnA] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ColumnB] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ColumnC] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL
) 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[sourceData] ([id], [ColumnA], [ColumnB], [ColumnC], [StartDate], [EndDate]) VALUES (1, 'aa', N'bb', N'cc', GETDATE())
GO
```

The query I am using to pull the table column names is:

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'sourceData'
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening of a 1 row table into a key-value pair table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341143/flattening-of-a-1-row-table-into-a-key-value-pair-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option that may help you create something more like an EAV structure

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] varchar(50),[ColumnA] varchar(50),[ColumnB] varchar(50),[ColumnC] varchar(50),[StartDate] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'aa','bb','cc','2016-10-10')


Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','OtherColumnsTo','Exclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Field       Value
1   ColumnA     aa
1   ColumnB     bb
1   ColumnC     cc
1   StartDate   2016-10-10
```

Comment: When I see a query with `cross apply` and XML functions, it is generally yours.  Kudos on having figured that stuff out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks.  I'm just a lazy, lazy man who has had to consume some ridiculous structures...   :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Following Solution, I have Referred from the following article to write this query:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-pivoting-data-in-sql-server-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/

```
USE [ToDelete]
GO
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(2000);DECLARE @col AS NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @col1 AS NVARCHAR(2000);

SELECT @col = ISNULL(@col + ', ', '') + 
concat('cast(',QUOTENAME(column_name),'as nvarchar(max))',' ',
QUOTENAME(column_name) ),@col1=ISNULL(@col1 + ', ', '') +QUOTENAME(column_name)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='sourceData') AS Colname;

SET @sql =N'select columnname,[values] from (select '+@col+ ' from dbo.sourceData) as D Unpivot
([values] for columnname in (' + @col1 + '))
as unpiv'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Union all` like this:

```
select Id,'ColumnA' columnName, ColumnA  [Values]
from t
union all
select Id,'ColumnB' , ColumnB 
from t
union all
select Id,'ColumnC' , ColumnC
from t
union all
select Id,'StartDate' , cast(StartDate as nvarchar(max))
from t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c575d/1)

Answer (score 0):

Additional variant using `unpivot`:

**dataset**

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
([Id]        VARCHAR(10),
 [ColumnA]   VARCHAR(10),
 [ColumnB]   VARCHAR(10),
 [ColumnC]   VARCHAR(10),
 [StartDate] DATE
);
INSERT INTO @YourTable
VALUES
(1, 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', '2016-10-10'),
(2, 'cc', 'dd', 'zz', '2016-10-11');
```

**query**

```
SELECT Id,
       Field,
       [Value]
FROM
(   SELECT Id,
           ColumnA,
           ColumnB,
           ColumnC,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM @YourTable
) AS t UNPIVOT([Value] FOR [Field] IN ( ColumnA,
                                        ColumnB,
                                        ColumnC,
                                        StartDate)) up;
```